# passing a parameter to other url that is already received in template from Django view

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to pass a parameter in url as a href tag but somehow it is not working.

```
{% if alertdata %}
                                {% for alertinfo in alertdata %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="{% url 'checks:alertflowdetail' alertid={{ alertinfo.alertid }} %}">{{ alertinfo.alertid }}</a> </td>
                                        <td>{{ alertinfo.alertdate }} </td>
                                        <td>{{ alertinfo.alerttype }} </td>
                                        <td>{{ alertinfo.alertdetails }} </td>
                                        <td>{{ alertinfo.alertcustomer }} </td>
                                        <td>{{ alertinfo.alertcomments }} </td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
```

Some how it gives me an error "Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'"

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `{{}}` around `alertinfo.alertid`:

```
"{% url 'checks:alertflowdetail' alertid=alertinfo.alertid %}"
```

templatetags know how to evaluate variables from the context, the `{{ somevar }}` notation is only to render a variable in the template.